# LabVIEW: converting numeric array to string array

Tags: arrays, labview

Using LabVIEW 2009, I have a VI that outputs an array of U64 integers.

I'd like the user to be able to perform discrete selection from among the elements of this array.

I'm thinking of accomplishing this by programmatically populating a Menu Ring
(as shown at http://digital.ni.com/public.nsf/allkb/FB0409491FAB16FA86256D08004FCE7E).

However, I apparently need to convert my array of U64 ints to an array of strings,
as it is an array of *strings* that is used to populate the Menu Ring.

My question:  how can I convert the array of U64 ints to an array of strings?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you try the Number to Decimal String primitive from the String\Conversion palette? It should even accept an array.

I'm not sure if it will work on U64 numbers, because I seem to have a vague memory of it coercing number to I32, but it probably will. In any case, if you want the actual value of the ring control to be the number you want, be sure to change the representation of the ring control to U64.

Comment: How about Format Into String?

Comment: This seems to work over the range, but there's a type coercion dot for array inputs that's a little disturbing... In any event, in LV2009, doubles and ext (but not ints) are converted to I64's before formatting.

Answer (score 0):

Format Into String seems to work (although it won't accept arrays, so you'll have to loop over it).